# firestore web v9 how to get all docs from all subCollection of a single parent collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

my data is structured like this:

```
appointments
  -city
    - store
      -month
        -day
          ....docs
```

i want to query the database to search within all appointments. how do i do that?

i've tried searching firebase docs, and i didn't find any solution. its mind boggling to me that `getDocs(collection(db,'appointments'))` is written under the hood in way that gives me 0 documents(to be clear he does not have any docs inside him. he has a subCollection that subCollection, there are documents)

Comment: I did a web search for "stack overflow firestore get all documents in subcollection v9" to find solutions.

Comment: It sounds like you have not created any documents in the `appointments` collection, which means that `getDocs(collection(db,'appointments'))` correctly returns no results. If you want to be able to load all appointments from `appointments`, you wll have to create documents in there - not just a subcollection under it.